# category images not showing up

Tags: image, upgrade

i have just cloned my website and then updated the cloned website. Everything works perfec except the images for my sub categories isnt showing up, my product images are just not the sub category images.

My code for looks like this:

```
<div class="subcategory-products">

<ul class="products-grid two_columns_5">
<?php
$_categories=$this->getCurrentChildCategories();
if($_categories->count()):
$categorycount = 0;
foreach ($_categories as $_category):
if($_category->getIsActive()):
$cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
$catName = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getName();
if ($categorycount == 0){
$class = "first";
}
elseif ($categorycount == 3){
$class = "last";
}
else{
$class = "";
}
?>
<li class="item <?=$class?>">
<a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" 
title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>">
<img class="pic_size_subcat" src="<?php echo $_category->getImageUrl() ?>" width="100" alt="
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" /></a>
<h2><a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a></h2>
</li>
<?php
endif;
if($categorycount == 3){
$categorycount = 0;
echo "</ul>\n\n<ul class=\"products-grid two_columns_5\">";
}
else{
$categorycount++;
}
endforeach;
endif;
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

but when i inspect the element in my web browser it shows this -

```
<img class="pic_size_subcat" src="" width="100" alt="
">
```

so all i can tell is that it is reading in the code correctly but it isnt getting the img src. Does anybody know why? it worked before i cloned the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, this is nearly always a file permission issue. Make sure that  the webserver has write permissions on the `media` and `var` directory. If you set the permissions, make sure you set them recursively.

Comment: Both permissions are set to 0777 and still not working ?

Comment: The problem was i had edited a core file and then when i upgraded it reset so i made a sub file and used that instead thank you for your suggestion though